# PyQt5: QSortFilterProxyModel causes table view header to reset its section resize mode

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have a table view with a visible header. To use the power of sorting I use QSortFilterProxyModel as a wrapper model. I also want my table header to stretch to fit the table width:

```
 horizontal_header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

And it works UNTIL I press on any of columns (to sort items). After I do so, header shrinks back to its default size. HOWEVER, if I add a row to the table BEFORE clicking on a header, headers size stays unchanged. So, here is the problem test case:

1. Table initialized with stretched header
2. Press on header to sort things
3. Header shrinks

TC2:

1. Table initialized with stretched header
2. Add a row to the table
3. Press on header to sort things
4. Header does not shrink.

NOTE: This does not happen if I don't use QSortFilterProxyModel

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that I didn't post minimal example for this, but for anyone who understood my problem and faces the same one here is how I managed to fix it:
Just subclass QSortFilterProxyModel and override sort() method:

```
class MySortModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def sort(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check that there is no data to sort, if so - do not sort
        if self.sourceModel().rowCount(QModelIndex()) > 0:
            super().sort(*args, **kwargs)
```

The idea is to disable sorting if there are no items in model

Comment: what is `table_item`?

Comment: @eyllanesc internal data structure, its specific for each project

Comment: Your solution does not seem like a quality solution but you explain details like that because without it your answer will not be useful for others, I want to give you a downvote now.

Comment: What is the difference between `self.sourceModel().table_item.row_count()`and `self.sourceModel().rowCount()`?

Comment: row_count is my wrapper around rowCount() method which requires QModelIndex() object which is hard to get sometimes. Edited the answer and excluded custom project logic. Sorry to hear you downvoted because I struggled for a long time and didn't find anything even close to my problem so I wrote my own solution so people who struggle with this could use it. Also, pasting the whole model code, rewriting it to exclude custom logic takes very much time and it'd be really huge and just confuse people.

Comment: My downvote was going to give it, but I have not. Remember that SO is a community, and the answers should not only serve you but the entire community (that's for all answers including autoresponders), and therefore must be replicable and for this it is necessary that if you use extra things the If they are elements of the library, the explanation can be omitte :D